# Unicode bold and color codes

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to pass Unicode codes to set bold and color but I'm not sure how or if this is possible. I have searched and not found any documentation on it, so I'm assuming it cannot be done.

So, in the following code example, I am sending the word 'Hello' in bold, which does work.

```
<?php
function utf8_bytes($cp){
        if ($cp > 0x10000){
            # 4 bytes
            return  chr(0xF0 | (($cp & 0x1C0000) >> 18)).
                chr(0x80 | (($cp & 0x3F000) >> 12)).
                chr(0x80 | (($cp & 0xFC0) >> 6)).
                chr(0x80 | ($cp & 0x3F));
        }
    }

$send = utf8_bytes("119815") .
utf8_bytes("119838") . 
utf8_bytes("119845") . 
utf8_bytes("119845") . 
utf8_bytes("119848"); 
?>
```

In the above, $send gives me 'Hello' in 'MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL' font. Specifically, the first code sent is 119815 which equates to:
U+1D407 - &#119815 - MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL H as taken from this link http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl

But what I really want to do is send a 'bold' Unicode code rather than trying to send bold characters for each letter. I also haven't found anything for changing the colour.

Am I going to be able to achieve this, or are there no codes that I can send for bold/italic/color?

Comment: Unicode doesn't have the concepts of bold (except for *a few* mathematical symbols), fonts or colour.

Comment: @Biffen, OK, I figured as much but wasn't sure, hence asking. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: The standard contains a note recommending against using these mathematical symbols instead of markup → [PDF](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D400.pdf). They are intended for mathematical formulas where eg. a bold letter has a different meaning than the non-bold letter.